# How to modify index type in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, ssms-2017

I need to change the type of index from "Unique Key" to "index". 
I`ve spent 2 days trying to drop and recreate it. Unfortunately, there are a lot of dependencies and the only way to fix my issue is to modify the existing index. SSMS visual editor allows me to change type however I ought to find out how to make it programmatically.

It is really bad idea to use something like `UPDATE sys.key_constraints SET type = 'UQ' WHERE ...`
Such a solution is not working properly.

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: I removed the PS as the question in it is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yes, it is a really bad idea to run an update against a sys table.

Comment: You can do it in management studio, but instead of saving it, you can generate a script.

Comment: Thank you, @Wouter!!! It works!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

To implement such change you will need to drop and recreate the index.
There is no alter statement that would change it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Piotr!
Unfortunately, it is impossible to DROP this index before I`ll manually change the type using SSMS visual tools. Is there any way to run "FORCE" dropping query?

Comment: What do you mean? - please post the error you are getting.

Comment: `The explicit DROP INDEX statement is not valid in the "controller.IX_controller" index. It is used to enforce the UNIQUE KEY constraint`.

Comment: You need to drop UNIQUE constraint before dropping the index. This constraint wouldn't be valid without unique index.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to drop the index as a constant:

`BEGIN TRANSACTION
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET ARITHABORT ON
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
COMMIT
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.table_name
    DROP CONSTRAINT IX_CONSTAINT_NAME
GO`